# Cyclic Redundancy Check - Message starting with 0

Tags: crc

I'm wondering how to encode a message starting with 0.
ie. Given
code: 10111
message: 001011110
I've tried divide this multiple times but am not sure if I can ignore the first two zeros of the message as they correspond to x^7 and x^8...
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If the crc is initialized to zero, then leading zeroes in the message to be encoded won't affect the crc. If the crc is initialized to some non-zero value, then it will get cycled each 0 bit encountered.